# Vaadin and Spring security - expire session on logout

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin7

I'm trying to implement logout feature for my vaadin and spring security application. I made custom security service that handles login and logout methods. So therefore while I login at first tab and open another tab (so in both tabs I authorized) and logout at one of them, the second gives communication error (while I click on any buttons or polling events are fired). While I'm expecting "Session timeout message".

```
public void logout() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    Optional.ofNullable( VaadinSession.getCurrent() )
.ifPresent( session -> session.close() );

}
```

also

```
session.getSession().invalidate()
```

didn't help.